# Android Spinner create and infinite loop?

Tags: android, if-statement, android-spinner

I am new to android ad i tried to create a spinner to change the language inside the app
through localehelper and i had to use recreate method for the app to reload with the appropriate string resources 
But the spinner created an infinite loop and keep calling the recreate method over and over and refreshing the activity 
here is the code for it

```
languageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapter, View v, int i, long lng) {
           int mNumber = 0;
           if(i == 0){
               LocaleHelper.setLocale(MainActivity.this, mLanguageCodeEn);
               recreate();
               mNumber = 1;
           }else if(i == 1){
               LocaleHelper.setLocale(MainActivity.this, mLanguageCodeAr);
               recreate();
               mNumber = 0;
           }
           if(mNumber == 1){
               languageSpinner.setSelection(0, false);
           }else if (mNumber == 0){
               languageSpinner.setSelection(1, false);
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView arg0) {
        }
    });
```

i tried to find a way around this issue and use a variable (mNumber) to cause the onItemSelected to be ignored if mNumber matches the value in that the
if statement assign to it but that didnt work

Comment: Do you call languageSpinner.setSelection(0,false); inside your activity? maybe after you initialized your spinner?

Comment: have you declared spinner onItemSelectedListener?

Comment: yes i have declared spinner onItemSelectedListener